# Sitecore 10.3 Constellation MVC contextitem not returning page ID

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

Recently upgraded Sitecore constellation from 9.3 to 10.3, post upgradation `contextitem` returning datasource ID instead of page ID. This feature working fine in 9.3 Sitecore instance.

`protected override object GetModel(Item datasource, Item contextItem){}`

In above code datasource and ContextItem both return datasource ID only.

Could some help me here if I am missing something?.

Answer (score 1):

A change was made to the `RenderingContext` in version 10.3. Prior to 10.3 the `RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem` property was set to:

- The ancestor rendering’s datasource item (if non-null)
- The page item

As of 10.3 the `RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem` property is set to:

- The current rendering’s datasource item (if non-null)
- The ancestor rendering’s datasource item (if non-null)
- The page item

You may need to update your code to account for the change in behavior. The `Context.Current.Page` property can be used to get the page context object.

```
var item = Sitecore.Context.Current.Page;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: we have more than 100 controllers this feature , could you please suggest best approach ?.

Comment: Well, it depends on your code structure.